Clarification on Equivalence of Linear Equations: $Ax=b$ vs. $A^\top A x = A^\top b$
What are the differences between the equations $Ax=b$ and $A^\top A x = A^\top b$? Initially, it seems like both involve similar operations, by considering the algebraic equivalence of equations like $x=2$ and $4x=8$, it's unclear why the presence of $A^\top$ in the second equation changes the interpretation(least square approximation). Additionally, if both equations are equivalent, why does the second equation, $A^\top A x = A^\top b$, approximate a solution using least squares approximation instead of the first one, $Ax=b$? If my understanding is incorrect or lacking in mathematical maturity, could you please clarify?

What does it mean �

@ТymaGaidash most likely emojis, the user is new so probably doens't know how to format

Please don't shout with boldface.

They're not equivalent. The equation $A^\top Ax = A^\top b$ is guaranteed to have a solution, even when $Ax = b$ does not. If $Ax = b$ has a solution, then those solution(s) will be precisely the solutions to $A^\top Ax = A^\top b$. But, if $Ax = b$ has no solution, the solution(s) to $A^\top Ax = A^\top b$ will be the value(s) of $x$ for which $Ax$ is as close to $b$ as possible (i.e. the least squares approximation). Also note: unlike with multiplying by non-zero real numbers like $4$, multiplying by matrices cannot be undone unless the matrix is square.

These two equations are not equivalent. Let's label the equations:
\begin{align}
Ax &= b \tag{1} \\
A^\top Ax &= A^\top b \tag{2}
\end{align}
It's clear that $(1) \implies (2)$, since $(2)$ is formed by multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by $A^\top$. This means that every solution to $(1)$ is a solution to is a solution to $(2)$. It does not imply that any solution to $(2)$ is a solution to $(1)$. Unless we can somehow show that $(2) \implies (1)$, as far as we know, $(2)$ produces more solutions than $(1)$.
Why is this different to the real numbers? Consider equations $2x = 4$ and $6x = 12$. We can get from the first solution to the second by multiplying both sides by $3$, so every solution to $2x = 4$ is a solution to $6x = 12$. Unlike in the matrix case, we can also get from $6x = 12$ back to $2x = 4$, simply because division by non-zero numbers is a thing in the real numbers (or, if you prefer, we can multiply both sides by $3^{-1} = 1/3$). So, every solution to $6x = 12$ is also a solution to $2x = 4$, which shows the solution sets are the same.
Unlike with real numbers, with matrices, multiplying by a non-zero matrix cannot be undone in this way. Not every matrix has an inverse. In particular, if $A^\top$ is not a square matrix (and frequently, it isn't with least squares), then $A^\top$ cannot be invertible. It doesn't necessarily mean that $(2)$ does not imply $(1)$, but it shows that our intuition from real numbers doesn't carry over here.
As it turns out, $(2)$ and $(1)$ are not generally equivalent, and this is a feature, not a bug. As you seem to be aware, $(2)$ is used to compute the least square solution. That is, it is used to find the $x$ such that $Ax$ is as close to $b$ as possible.
If there is a solution to $(1)$, i.e. there are actual values of $x$ that produce $Ax = b$, then $Ax$ is distance $0$ from $b$ (which is the minimum possible), which makes these values of $x$ the least squares solution. In this particular scenario, $(1)$ happens to be equivalent to $(2)$: they have the same solutions.
If there is no solution to $(1)$, then $(2)$ becomes more interesting. It turns out that $(2)$ always has a solution. This tells us that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are not equivalent in this case. The solutions to $(2)$ put $Ax$ as close as possible to $b$. So, even though we can't make $Ax$ equal $b$, we get the next best thing.
So, in short: $Ax = b$ and $A^\top A x = A^\top b$ are not always equivalent, depending on whether $Ax = b$ has a solution or not. If $Ax = b$ has a solution, then they are equivalent. If $Ax = b$ has no solution, then $A^\top A x = A^\top b$ will still have solutions (least square solutions), making them not equivalent.

Is this the reason we know that statement (2) is not equivalent to statement (1) — because (2) produces more solutions than (1)? Overall, it was a very satisfying answer.

@Praveen Yes, exactly.
